# How do you bulk move files and directories with PHP

Tags: php

I have a site with many files and directories. The directories are several levels deep. The problem is that they are in the wrong directory. They are in `/www/upload/site/` and everything should be moved to `/www/`. Is there a short script to move everything two directories up?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it *have* to be a PHP script? Your FTP client should be able to do this, or you could do it with a shell.

Comment: The problem is that the site is on Godaddy and for some network problem I cannot access the control panel directly, neither can use FTP. The only access I have is through a VPN, which does not allow me to upload files. Actually I had the files in there by the help of a friend, but they ended in the wrong directory. I can use the control panel's `new file` and make a small script to run through the VPN.

Comment: I vomit at the mere mention of the name GoDaddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by other answerer, PHP isn't the most elegant solution for this and it'd be far easier to just download an FTP program to move the files with. However, if you do want to implement this using PHP, you could write something like:

```
$dir=opendir('/www/upload/site/');

while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue; // skip references to self

    rename('/www/upload/site/'.$file, '/www/'.$file);
}

closedir($dir);
```

This process is inefficient and is brought about as easier methods such as using the [Rename Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) or [Copy Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) won't work in your case. Rename would require the directory you're 'renaming to' to be empty which it isn't as you're moving from within it, copy cannot copy complete directories. Therefore, we are left with the process or looping through each file and moving it to a new location manually using PHP's rename function on each individual item.

So whilst this process is certainly not one which PHP is necessary for, it's perfectly possible to do it and it's always useful to have the know how. It'd be worth reading up on [PHP's File System Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) for more information on working with files/dirs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a script. Get a good ftp program, such as [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) or [FireFTP](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/) (needs firefox), and you could simply select all, and drag all folders and files in `www/upload/` to `www/upload`, and the ftp program will move them for you.

Comment: The FTP option is not available as I explained in a comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know how the server is set up, but probably this will not work as the user running the php script is not likely to have permissions to move files that you uploaded (unless they were uploaded using a php script as well...).

You could of course try something like:

```
<?php
    exec('mv /www/upload/site/* /www');
?>
```

but I would be very careful with that.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think that would work on a shard hosting.

Comment: There are plenty of shared hosting solutions where you have shell access, but I don´t know godaddy. Have you tried it?

Comment: An anonymous user tried to make the following comment in an edit: *worked for me, but rename directories that have spaces anywhere in the path*.